# ProxyPassMatch regex does not match

Tags: regex, apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

Using Apache 2.2.15, I'm trying to set a ProxyPassMatch rule that matches the following request only when the "year" parameter is equal to 2015:

```
/my-servlet/DownloadPdf?param1=40978659700000&year=2015&param3=testrv%2540rv.com
```

I know that the following configuration matches my request and works:

```
ProxyPassMatch /my-servlet/(.*)$ balancer://mycluster
```

But I want something like this, and it doesn't work:

```
ProxyPassMatch /my-servlet/(.*year=2015.*)$ balancer://mycluster
```

I have also tried other regex that match the request, unsucessfully:

```
ProxyPassMatch /my-servlet/.*year=2015.* balancer://mycluster
ProxyPassMatch /my-servlet/.*year=2015.*$ balancer://mycluster
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: `ProxyPassMatch /my-servlet/(.*year=2015.*)$ balancer://mycluster` should match... Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from [mod_proxy docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
The path is the name of a local virtual path; url is a partial URL for the remote server and cannot include a query string.
```

Didn't test it, but a possible workaround:

```
RewriteEnginge On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} year=2015
RewriteRule (.*) balancer://mycluster [P]
```

Let us know, if it did the job and even more so, if it didn't ;)

Comment: I had to use the following configuration

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} year=2015
RewriteRule (.*) balancer://mycluster/my-servlet/DownloadPdf [P]

Comment: So, exactly what I suggested, but with the real target-URI?! Sounds good :)